# How to align text correctly in UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone

say that I have a string "ABCDEDGHIJK"
what I want is to align it to be like this in a `UILabel`:

```
   ABC
DEFGHI
```

while I set the **textAlignment** to **NSTextAlignmentRight** ,it got something like:

```
ABCDEF
   GHI
```

While the whole string is not exactly as long as the length of 2 lines,How can the bottom is filled and leaving the top line to be filled the rest of the word

Comment: Dis you try to set the `lineBreakMode` with `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`?